# ag-grid react export to excel column expanding in excel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, ag-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq7GK.png)
 I need to achieve this functionality in ag-grid . could someone help me out on column expanding in excel to export

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at from the image. Can you describe the functionality with words?

Comment: Hi I need to achieve expanding and collapsing in Excel through export to excel in ag grid. Is there any library that we can achieve row expand and collapse in excel

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like a combination of row grouping and excel import.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/
https://www.ag-grid.com/example-excel-import/

Comment: Yes that is my problem .By default, row groups are exported with the names of each node in the hierarchy combined together, like "-> Parent -> Child". But i want to have expand and collapse in the excel same like grid

Comment: There is no simple solution, you'll have to figure it out using the links provided above unfortunately.